# issue changing div inner html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have done this previously the same way and now have no idea why it isn't working.

My current function

```
function refreshTable() 
{

var filters = ["Park", "Building", "Room", "Week"];

var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];

var times = ["9:00-9:50", "10:00-10:50", "11:00-11:50",
             "12:00-12:50", "13:00-13:50", "14:00-14:50", 
             "15:00-15:50","16:00-16:50", "17:00-17:50"];

var tableHTML = "<table><tr><th></th>";

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
{

tableHTML += "<th>" + times[i] + "</th>";

}

tableHTML += "</tr>";

for (var k = 0; k < 5; k++) 
{

tableHTML += "<tr><th>" + days[k] + "</th>";

  for (var l = 0; l < 9; l++) 
  {
   tableHTML += "<td class='availability'></td>"
  }

tableHTML += "</tr>"

}

tableHTML += "</table>";

alert(tableHTML);

$('#tableDiv').html(tableHTML);

}
```

The html is alerted properly and is correctly formatted, but will not post to the html of the div tag.

Comment: It will work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/QUP3g/ Please check your browser console for errors. Check your jquery lib path whether its loading or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check have you included jquery library on the page,if not include it and use firebug console to check if any syntax mistake you are doing, may be some parenthesis open or close missing, the code you shared is absolutely write, it should work, i am afraid you have nor including jquery script file.

Comment: Thanks, I had put it in earlier I must have taken it out when getting rid of something else -_- silly mistake